# SLA on Operator start time

Tags: airflow

I have created a DAG, which starts at midnight every day of the week. It contains a sensor that waits for an event to occur in a database after which the actual work starts. The event can occur 1 minutes after the DAG starts or 10 hours after the DAG starts (and that is fine). I do not want to include the time spent waiting for the sensor to proceed in the SLA.

So, what I want to do is to manage an SLA on the **operator execution time** rather than the DAG end to end. Is that possible?

Below will manage since the DAG started (although the SLA is defined on the Operator)

```
DEFAULT_ARGS = {
    'owner': 'abc@def.com',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 3, 1)
}

with DAG('Start a job',
         description='Start DAG which waits for event and then executes the job.',
         catchup=False,
         schedule_interval="0 0 * * 1-5",
         default_args=DEFAULT_ARGS) as dag:

    DWH_SENSOR = WarehouseMilestoneSensor(
        task_id="wait_for_warehouse_milestone"
    )

    START_JOB = SqlAgentOperator(job_name='ClientValueScore',
                                  await_completion=True,
                                  mssql_conn_id="sqlagent",
                                  task_id="start-ClientValueScore-job",
                                  sla=timedelta(minutes=150))

    DWH_SENSOR >> START_JOB
```